# ant design autfocus bug

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, react-typescript

Is there a bug with ant design autoFocus when implemented within a modal?

Passing `autoFocus = {true}` as a prop on the input element is not working for me

I have tried several of these hack methods found here https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-autofocus-using-react-hooks/, but sadly none have worked for me

I also found a GitHub issue https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/41239 which seems to highlight that this issue is related to ant design version 4.24.0.. I am using 4.24.7, could this be the cause?